# Do cockroaches lay eggs in human flesh when they "bite"?

Tags: zoology, entomology

Recently, I discovered a "bite" by a cockroach, and not only is the "bitten" area red and swallowing, and more specifically, it have a big hole in that area, but when I clean it with hydrogen peroxide solution, something is happening, that is, a yellowish/greenish thing comes out from the holes from each infecting area.

Do cockroaches lay eggs in human flesh when they "bite", and much more importantly, would hydroxide solution kill the eggs and parasites inside those of those holes?

Comment: I assume you mean peroxide solution (hydrogen peroxide); not hydroxide (e.g. sodium hydroxide, a strong base).

Comment: @NickT - Wow, how do you know?

Comment: Because hydroxide solutions are not usually for-sale unless you're looking in the plumbing aisle.

Comment: Whilst asking if cockroaches embed eggs in their bites is fine, I'm a little concerned that asking if *hydrogen peroxide that I'm putting into the cockroach bite that I sustained* is really on the edge of asking for medical advice, which is off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, cockroaches do not lay eggs into human flesh. You most likely received an infection of some sort from the bug, or it wasn't a cockroach.

Comment: the yellow/green liquid is probably pus